# Entity Framework Access multiple select statements

Tags: entity-framework, list, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

my stored procedure returns 3 select statements. using entity framework how can access the particular select statement.
In ADO.Net using "DATASET" we can access particular table. like

```
DataSet ds = GetApplicationSummary(appId);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

now we can access the Table[0] of data. same as next two tables.

**Using EntityFramework how can access 3 select statements data.** please can any help this.

Comment: was my answer what you were looking for? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can access multiple result sets by `GetNextResult`. Here's a code sample from Microsoft.

```
using (var db = new BlogEntities())
{
    var results = db.GetAllBlogsAndPosts();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Blog: " + result.Name);
    }

    var posts = results.GetNextResult<Post>();

    foreach (var result in posts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post: " + result.Title);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Check out [this by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402) for more information.